# java question on certificates signing process

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I am confused on the process to create a valid certificate,signed by a CA, in java.
I know that java has the tool `keytool` to create public-private keys and certificates.
Also it supports JKS and PKCS#12.
So one can create a keystore with a public-private key pair and a certificate e.g.
`keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias aCert -keystore someKeystore.keystore`
This will create a keystore with a certificate (self-signed).
So far I understand.
I can export the certificate for a csr request to send to a CA e.g. Verisign, without the private key of course.
After this part I am lost.
The CA will sign it and I will have to re-import it to my keystore?This will replace the original certificate already in keystore?
It will still be self-signed though.
Shouldn't the issuer be the CA itself?But then how is this possible?I just send the public key only and not a certificate?
Any help on clearing the process please?
**UPDATE**:
Is the CA signing the certificate (e.g. Verisign) also the issuer?Or it can sign a certificate that the `issuer==subject`?
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about how to set up a Java keystore with a signed cert or how the certificate signing process in general works?

Comment: Oftentimes the CA will provide a support forum or FAQ about how to create your CSR, get your CRT, and subsequently install it into your environment. They usually have such steps for most of the commonly-used platforms. I'm not an SSL guru (and don't trust myself to provide an actual answer to your question), but I find these resources a good place to start when working with certificates. As an example, here's a [Java/keytool thread](https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?t=1390) from StartCom's support forums.

Comment: @JeffB:I am asking how to properly use java keytool/keystore in the certificate signing process

Comment: @Rob Hruska:In the link you posted, the instructions are to create a certificate with the issuer and the subject is `www.domain.com`.At least after trying the `keytool -genkey -alias http://www.domain.com -dname "cn=www.domain.com, o=domain, o=.com"
` they suggest the certificate I see created has issuer=subject=domain.com.Is the subject supposed to change?I do not see this mentioned in the thread though

Comment: The original certificate (created via `keytool -genkey`) will be self-signed, with issuer=subject=domain.com. The file that comes back from StartCom (`www.domain.com.signed.crt`) will contain a certificate with subject=domain.com and issuer=StartCom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct up to the point of CSR creation. You'll use something like this:

```
$ keytool -certreq -alias myalias -file myalias.csr -keystore keystore
```

to generate a CSR, which contains:

- your public key (extracted from the self-signed cert)
- the Distinguished Name (i.e. the name of the entity for whom the cert is requested)

and is signed with your private key. The CA then generates a new certificate with:

- subject = your DN (either from the CSR or auto-generated using details you supplied during the application process)
- issuer = the CA's DN
- public key = from the CSR

which you need to import back into your keystore, *replacing* the original self-signed cert:

```
$ keytool -import -alias myalias -keystore keystore -file myalias.crt
```

Often CAs will sign your new certificate using an *intermediate* certificate which is in turn signed by a trusted root; in this case you should import the intermediate certificate before your own:

```
$ keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file intermediate.crt -keystore keystore
```

**Edit:** this obscure section from keytool's documentation is surprisingly clear (where it talks about a 'chain' of certificates, this just refers to the intermediate certificates that link yours to the root):

> keytool can create and manage keystore "key" entries that each contain a private key and an associated certificate "chain". The first certificate in the chain contains the public key corresponding to the private key.
>
> When keys are first generated (see the -genkey  subcommand),  the  chain starts  off  containing  a  single element, a self-signed certificate. A self-signed certificate is one for which the issuer (signer) is the same as  the  subject  (the entity whose public key is being authenticated by the certificate). Whenever the -genkey subcommand is called to  generate a new public/private key pair, it also wraps the public key into a self-signed certificate.
>
> Later, after a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) has been generated (see the -certreq subcommand) and sent to a Certification Authority (CA), the response from the CA is imported (see -import), and the self-signed certificate  is  replaced  by a chain of certificates. At the bottom of the chain is the certificate (reply) issued by  the  CA  authenticating  the subject's  public  key.  The  next  certificate in the chain is one that authenticates the CA's public key.

Comment: But how is the original self-signed cert in the keystore replaced?I mean, the keystore somehow I guess associates public-private key pairs to certificates, right?And the certificate contains the public key.So do we delete somehow the original certificate?But leave private-public key pair intact?

Comment: @user384706: I've now included the commands to import the new certificate. If the alias (`myalias` above) references an existing key, keytool ensures that the public key matches the new certificate and, if so, imports the new certificate to replace the original.

Comment: And yes, the new cert will contain the public key (copied from the CSR). The private key remains in your keystore the whole time.

Comment: I see.The alias (in the example `myalias`) does not refer to a certificate?It refers to a key?

Comment: The alias refers to the combination of private key and certificate (which contains your public key). The certificate gets replaced; the new certificate contains the same public key; the private key remains intact.

Comment: I found this in the keytool 1.6 documentation under the topic Importing a Certificate Reply. 

"If the public key in the certificate reply matches the user's public key already stored with under alias, the old certificate chain is replaced with the new certificate chain in the reply. The old chain can only be replaced if a valid keypass, the password used to protect the private key of the entry, is supplied. If no password is provided, and the private key password is different from the keystore password, the user is prompted for it."

Answer (score 2):

After the CA signs the cert it ceases to be self-signed. A self-signed certificate has issuer == subject. When the CA signs it, issuer becomes the CA, which corresponds to the subject in the CA's own certificate, which in turn is signed by another issuer, ... so you have a certificate chain, that terminates in a trusted root that is already in your truststore.

Comment: Seems my misconception here.I thought self-sign and self-issued were different things.I.e. a certificate is issued by me, handed to e.g. Verisign which it signs it i.e. just creates a digital signature on it and I have a self-issued certificate with a signature of the CA. But how after CA signs it ceases to be self-signed?How did the issuer changed?

Comment: It ceases to be self-signed *because* the CA signed it. Actually the signed cert they return isn't the same as the CSR you sent them, but it has the same subject, OID, serial nos etc. When you import that into the keystore with an alias it replaces whatever cert already had that alias: in the normal case, that was the self-signed cert associated with the keypair.

Comment: @EJP *"It ceases to be self-signed because the CA signed it"* The CA requires identification (image of photo license, passport.. ) of the claimant as well as documentation or other evidence of the organization (e.g. domain/site).  That is the main reason they are *willing* to sign it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Of course, and that is what their signature implies, and when they do so it ceases to be self-signed. Your comment should be addressed to the OP, not me.

Comment: *"that is what their signature implies,"*  I thought it worth mentioning explicitly, since the OP still seemed confused as to *why* it made a difference. *"..Your comment should be addressed to the OP, not me"*  Maybe, but it was only that one small point I wanted to clarify.  I could move the comment to the question itself, but it loses some context, and would still quote your answer.  I'll leave it to your decision..  let me know & I'll move it, or if you feel the comment is not important enough, flag it for deletion.